# How to pause/resume or stop a thread and display a popup

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have the following code which displays 3...2...1 starting a thread:

```
...
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(3);
final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(n.get()));
        if(n.getAndDecrement() >= 1 )
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        else {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv.post(new Roller(900)); //tv is a textView
        }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(counter, 1000);
...
ImageButton ibStop;
ibStop.setOnClickListener(...() {
    //stop the thread
    //display a popup
});

ImageButton ibPause;
ibPause.setOnClickListener(...() {
    //pause the thread
    //display a popup
});

ImageButton ibPlay;
ibPlay.setOnClickListener(...() {
    //display the `handler` above with the 3...2...1...
    //resume the thread
});
```

Runnable:

```
private class Roller implements Runnable
{
    private long delayMillis;
    private Boolean stop = false;

    public Roller(long delayMillis)
    {
        this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 1;
        int n = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        String roll = String.valueOf(n);
        tv.setText("Random number is " + roll); //tv is a textview

        if (roll.equals("0")) {
            inType = 0;
            ibRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_selector);
            ibGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_dark);
        }
        if (roll.equals("1")) {
            inType = 1;
            ibRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dark);
            ibGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_selector);
        }

        tv.postDelayed(this, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Please help me with the stopping and pausing/resuming the thread.

Comment: you have to put a flag variable and change it, if you want to pause or continue to run.

Answer (score 3):

As @Alon suggested, you might need a flag variable to change in order to pause and restart the runnable. In particular you could attempt to use android's messaging system with the handler. Not sure if this is the "ideal method" but it's worked for me in the past:)

```
  boolean mRunning; int AYE_AYE_CAPTAIN=4; int MESSAGE_PAUSE=3; 
  int MESSAGE_RESUME=2;
  Runnable roller = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(mRunning) {
                    try {
                       // Do your stuff here.
                       /* In case you want to communicate with handler */
                       Message msg = new Message();
                       msg.what=AYE_AYE_CAPTAIN;
                       handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       // Not good!!!
                    }
                }
            }
        }, timeToRun,this);

        mRunning=true;
        roller.start();
```

And a handler to manage the thread runnable state.

```
   /** Handler to keep track of and manage thread runnable state */
   handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MESSAGE_PAUSE:
                        // Take an action 
                        mRunning=false;
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_RESUME;
                        mRunning = true;
                        // Restart Runnable here.
                        roller.start();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

Then perform the pause or resume options through messages.

```
public void main sendLifeCycleMessage(int MESSAGE) {
    Message awesomeMessage = new Message();

    awesomeMessage.what = MESSAGE; //
    roller.sendMessage(awesomeMessage);
    /* alternatively if your calling from a service:
    mService.getHandler().sendMessage(awesomeMessage);
    */
```

Comment: How are they added in the activity?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: That's up to you. I was demonstrating the concept.  You could probably add my run() loop to to your current one. And the handler into the calling activity. The ibStop and ibStart would likely trigger the method ive named sendLifeCycleMessage. But all of this is up to you :)

Comment: So i am getting rid of the runnable function and instead using it inline?

Comment: I just used a boolean to set whether the runnable is "running" or not and the same wat I stopped it. Thank you for the help.