# How to create Life Cycle Aware Handler in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-handler

First of all, I know how to create Handler.

I am working on a project where I am using `Handler` with `postDelayed`. There are some times when app got crashed because **activity was destroyed and the task inside the handler executes after activity destroy**.

I am looking for an alternative of Handler which can execute after a delay and it could be Lifecycle Aware so that the app won't get crash.

I know how to cancel Handler (removing Handler or cancelling handler inside onDestroy/onStop methods of activity), here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4378533/8874958) for the same. But I am not looking for these solutions. Any alternative would be a better solution if one can have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add a boolean in onPause, onResume. If its false, do not run the code

Answer (score 4):

Depending on if you're using java or Kotlin, you can use RxJava or coroutines for this.

### RxJava solution

```java
// this should be a member variable
private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

// this is how you launch the task that needs delay
Disposable d = Single.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(schedulers.ui())
    .subscribe(ignored -> {
        // you can manipulate the ui here
     });
        
// make sure to call disposables.clear() in onDestroyView
disposables.add(d);
```

#### Kotlin solution

```kotlin
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
   withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
       delay(2000)
   }
   // you can manipulate the ui here
}
```

As you can see the Kotlin + coroutines solution requires much less manual work, and it's harder to get wrong, so if you're on a Kotlin project I think you should use that one. Other alternative may be to use Guava `ListenableFuture`s but I haven't work with those yet.

Comment: There's no point in specifying a dispatcher to call a suspend function like `delay()`. It is the responsibility of the suspend function not to block and delegate itself if necessary.

Comment: Should we still be using RxJava?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you and your team already know it then yes ,it would be a fine choice. Or if your project is still mostly java then it's also a great choice. If you're in a greenfield project, and have the luxury to choose the tech, then I would suggest coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

if you are familiar and ok with using `coroutines`, you can replace `Handlers` to achieve the same functionality

using below dependency with coroutines you can make coroutines lifecycle aware

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
```

then in Activity

```
lifeCycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
     delay(1000)

     //do your work after delay, runs on main thread 
     //by default, will be cancelled if life cycle is inactive
}
```

More about using coroutines : [Deep Dive into Coroutines + Android](https://medium.com/@rajanks/deep-dive-into-kotlin-coroutines-android-c1256b42563b)

Comment: There's no point in specifying a dispatcher to call a suspend function like `delay()`. It is the responsibility of the suspend function not to block and delegate itself if necessary.

Comment: Makes sense, delay function in library will handle executing it on worker by default.

Comment: This is simple, and the cancellation will work well, exactly because of the delay().  But for some reason launchWhenStarted is deprecated without offering a good replacement. I do not understand why they offer repeatOnLifecycle, which is not doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `Handler` to execute delayed actions with `postDelayed()` you can run into troubles when the execution of the action happens after your Activity or Fragment has been destroyed.

There is a simple solution to this. Bind your Handler to the lifecycle.

### Create a LifecycleObserver

First lets create a `LifecycleObserver` that gets a `Handler` instance.
In the event of `Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY` it will remove all callbacks and messages from that `Handler`.

```kotlin
class LifecycleObververHandler(private val handler: Handler) : LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    internal fun onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
}
```

### Add the LifecycleObserver to the LifecycleOwner

Next we have to add the `LifecycleObververHandler` to a `LifecycleOwner`. We also wanna create these lifecycle observed handlers easily. So lets create a `LifecycleHandlerFactory`.

That factory gets created with a lambda `handlerFactory` that gives you an instance of a `Handler` (default is a `Handler` with a main Looper). It has one function `create` that expects a `LifecycleOwner`.

Within that function it checks that the state of the `Lifecycle` is not `DESTROYED`. It calls the `handlerFactory` to get an instance of `Handler`. Then it creates a `LifecycleObserverHandler`, which takes the handler, and adds that `Observer` to the `LifecycleOwner`. Finally the `Handler` gets returned.

```kotlin
class LifecycleHandlerFactory(private val handlerFactory: (() -> Handler) = { Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) }) {

    fun create(owner: LifecycleOwner): Handler {
        check(owner.lifecycle.currentState != Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
            "Cannot create a Handler for a destroyed life-cycle"
        }
        val handler = handlerFactory.invoke()
        val observer = LifecycleObververHandler(handler)
        owner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        return handler
    }
}
```

### Inject the lifecycle aware Handler

When you are using a DependendencyInjection Framework or a service locater like [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/) you can inject the lifecycle aware `Handler`.

```
module {
  // a single instance of LifecycleHandlerFactory
  // it gets a lambda that every time its being called returnes a new Handler with a main looper.
  single { LifecycleHandlerFactory() }
  
  // uses the LifecycleHandlerFactory to create a new handler with a LifecycleOwner as parameter.
  factory<Handler> { (lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) -> get<LifecycleHandlerFactory>().create(lifecycleOwner) }
}
```

Finally you can inject a lifecycle handler in your Fragment (or Activity).

```kotlin
// injects a new handler with a LifecycleOwner as a parameter
private val handler: Handler by inject { parametersOf(viewLifecycleOwner) }
```

Answer (score 0):

launchWhenResumed () is deprected now, seems a solution now would be something like:

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
            delay(2000)
            yourFunction()
        }
    }
```

You can use the following little helper:

```
fun LifecycleOwner.delayed(
    timeMillis: Long,
    state: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED,
    block: () -> Unit
) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(state) {
            delay(timeMillis)
            block()
        }
    }
}
```

Like in:

```
delayed(2000) { yourFunction() }
```

Comment: As the name repeatOnLifecycle suggests, this will repeat on each resume.