# How to stop the launch of a thread done with postDelayed

Tags: android, multithreading, postdelayed

I have a service tha launch a thread after 15 sec. This is a snippet of my code:

```
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        OverclockThread ocThread = new OverclockThread();
        ocThread.ocPreference = readPreference("oc");
        ocThread.serviceOn = true;

        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
            ocThread.screenOff = false;
            mHandler.postDelayed(ocThread, 15000);
        }
```

Now I'd like to add the ability to stop the launching of my ocThread before these 15 seconds...for example by pressing a button or a checkbox...which command I have to use to stop a thread launched with postDelayed?

thanks

simone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a runnable from a handler object added by postDelayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627216/how-to-remove-a-runnable-from-a-handler-object-added-by-postdelayed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'have used:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(ocThread);
```

Comment: can i also use emptyMessage since i just need it for timing purposed?