# RatingBar delay submission before set

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a `RatingBar` where a user can submit a star number.  I don't have a button with it, I want to make it more user friendly and let it submit dynamically.

In the `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` method, I submit the stars.

**Here is quesiton**

I'd like to put maybe a 1 second delay before submission, and if the user changes to a different star, reset the timer.

I'm trying to prevent multiple database submissions (or at least limit them).

Is this possible? and how can this be written?

Comment: "I'm trying to prevent multiple database submissions (or at least limit them).". so you can insert first rating and when user change their rating, update previous record without insert new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible. An ideal way to do this might be to create a `Handler` in your class. When the listener is called cancel a `Runnable` that contains the submission code and post it to run in 1 second. If it is the first time you get the call back the cancel will have no effect but that is fine. Make sure your Runnable is not an anonymous one so that there is only one instance of it so it can be cancelled.

Your question is similar to this one:

[How to remove a runnable from a handler object added by postDelayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627216/how-to-remove-a-runnable-from-a-handler-object-added-by-postdelayed)

Here is some code:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Runnable mSubmit = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Submit to server ...
    }
}

RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener mListener = 
        new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mSubmit);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mSubmit, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see exactly what you sure doing. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!